# SQL using minus function to eliminate rows from specific columns but returning all columns from table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to return all columns in a database where certain rows within certain columns have been eliminate. Is there any possible way to do this? I tried using code like this but I'm unsure what I am missing to make this work

```
Select * from table1
where (select column1 from table1
minus select column1 from table2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  T1.*
From    Table1  T1
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table2  T2
    Where   T2.Column1 = T1.Column1
)
```

Alternatively, you could use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
Select      T1.*
From        Table1  T1
Left Join   Table2  T2  On  T2.Column1 = T1.Column1
Where       T2.Column1 Is Null
```

Or even a `WHERE NOT IN`:

```
Select  *
From    Table1
Where   Column1 Not In 
(
    Select  Column1
    From    Table2
)
```

I would recommend the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` approach, but to fix the query you have in the question, you just need to add a `WHERE IN`:

```
Select  *
From    Table1
Where   Column1 In 
(
    Select  Column1
    From    Table1
    Minus
    Select  Column1
    From    Table2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
select * from table1 where  column1 in 
(select column1 from table1
minus 
select column1 from table2);